# How do I add Google Tag Manager on Blogger?

Tags: blogger, tag-manager

I tried to paste the code generated through Google Tag Manager to my blog and I verified that the code was copied exactly, but always I get the same message error:

> "The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter"

Answer (score 1):

I found this from [Claudia](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!profile/tag-manager/APn2wQfs6LEIxkerQYxomnwizTUyrPzlWSZtWr3S35pDpWQm6QyM5DOzESFHxQR-C7Pv_yEUb234)

This is a problem with blogger and GTM - blogger parses everything as XML which causes problems with the GTM tag.
Try the following:
In the code of your container tag you should see this line

```
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
```

replace that line with this line - the change is highlighted in bold

```
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&amp;l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
```

Then copy the adjusted code in your blogger template and save the template - it should work now. When you then check the source code of the website you can see that the '&' has been changed back by blogger to the correct '&', so the code that is actually included on the website is exactly the code that GTM requires.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/tag-manager/Jk9i2AWfDSg/FUeZ9gSv6gIJ)